# creating a chart with high/low and percentile box plus other points

Tags: python, matplotlib, finance

Hi I'd like to recreate the following plot with matplotlib and pandas.
I started to use boxplot but i'm struggling to manipulate the kwargs.
Is there a simple way to use boxplot or do I need to recreate the chart enitrely.
One issue I had was also adding the current data?
Best regards

[image: Correlation Plot]

Comment: Maybe you could add a minimal example of code that is failing and specify what is going wrong. In general, there are many ways to create a boxplot (e.g. https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html, http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/boxplot_demo.html), all of which seem perfectly able to recreate your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [boxplot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot) from matplotlib has indeed some limitations. For you to have full control over how the plot looks I would advise using [Patches](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html) to draw [Rectangles](http://matthiaseisen.com/pp/patterns/p0203/) for example (code from Rectangles link):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
ax1.add_patch(
    patches.Rectangle(
        (0.1, 0.1),   # (x,y)
        0.5,          # width
        0.5,          # height
    )
)
fig1.savefig('rect1.png', dpi=90, bbox_inches='tight')
```

This is useful because you'll only need this and a normal [plot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) command (for lines) in matplotlib to do a boxplot. This will give you immense control about color and shape and it's fairly easy to build. You also have text there you'll need for which you can use matplotlib [text](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text). The last thing are those markers which are very doable with a [scatter](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter).

A boxplot is a shape that tells you information such a minimum, maximum, and percentiles (25,50,75). You can calculate this very easily with numpy [percentile](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html).

The details of the plot (labels at the bottom, legend, title in box, and so on) can also be achieved but tinkering with labels, manually building a title box and so on.

It will give you some work but these are the commands you need.

Comment: thanks very much that's i believe is what I need. sorry but was a bit of a mess to find and trying to play with the boxplot was the wrong tactics. I'll play with that.